# Javascript webkit-fake-url

Tags: javascript, web-applications, image-processing

Id It possible when an image (for example) is pasted from the clipboard into a webkit editable content region, and the source code looks like this:

```
webkit-fake-url://DCAC99B9-BA40-4BA7-A419-9C60AAB081DA/image.png
```

to be able to access the image via javascript to send back to the server along with the text?

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive as to where you're inserting these images from/to, and where you're getting the webkit-fake-url from?

Comment: @GetFresh, this occurs when pasting actual image data into the contentEditable field (eg. copying an image from another application or another webpage).

Comment: To reproduce the a above behavior. 1) In a webkit browser right click an image & choose "Copy Image" 2) Go to http://ckeditor.com/demo 3) Use keyboard shortcuts to paste the image into the editor 4) Click the "Source" button in CKEditor to see the new <img> tag.

Answer (score 6):

Obviously you can use whatever abstraction for event listeners you like; I'm providing an unabstracted version; this will also exclude IE < 9

```
if('addEventListener' in editableElement) {
    editableElement.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
        // First two conditionals should weed out browsers which
        // don't allow access to pasted content
        if(('clipboardData' in e) && ('types' in e.clipboardData) &&
            e.clipboardData.types.indexOf('public.url') > 1) {
            e.target.ownerDocument.execCommand('insertImage', null,
                e.clipboardData.getData('public.url'));
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

When dealing with weirdness in WebKit pastes, it's a good idea to inspect the paste event's `clipboardData`:

```
console.dir(eventObj.clipboardData);
```

But in my experience, Web Inspector seems to inspect the live object in memory at the time the console is displayed, rather than the object at the time and in the scope `console.dir` was called. By this point, the `paste` event will have ended and Javascript's access to the clipboard will have been revoked, so that the `types` property will be `null` and the actual clipboard data will be hidden. But in your event, you can do this to get a better idea of what types are available and what their output would be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < eventObj.clipboardData.types.length; i++) {
    console.log(eventObj.clipboardData.types[i] + ':',
        eventObj.clipboardData.getData(eventObj.clipboardData.types[i]));
}
```

I've spent more time than I'd like to admit debugging `clipboardData` in WebKit browsers. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer, this has been helpful. Unfortunately for some reason when I log the contents of `clipboardData`, I get 4 types (public.tiff, image/tiff, public.png, image/png) but all appear as `undefined`. It appears things may have changed since you wrote this. Any idea how to get that data? Cheers.

Comment: At the moment (Safari 8.x) there's no way to get over the "`webkit-fake-url` problem" and get some real data. I investigated every single possible way  and summarised my impressions on [CKEditor bug tracker](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13029#comment:6).