# How to access webkit-fake-url

Tags: javascript, webkit

Using Safari (5.1.3) on OS X (10.7.3).

When a div is set to contenteditable="true" I am able to paste an image into it and see it. I can also drag an image in and see it.

I can also once it is there drag it around in the editable area.

The image has markup like this...

```
<img src="webkit-fake-url://8498873E-AAE1-478E-9731-A97A10CD7FEC/image.tiff">
```

Is there any known documentation on this. A search of google and so returns a lot of people asking the same question.

I would like to be able to send that image along to the server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript webkit-fake-url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108459/javascript-webkit-fake-url)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can edit any element's content. See [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) for available details. You can further experiment it to see if it can be used to send images to server. Even not with simple GET/POST you can always send editable element's content with javaScript/jQuery ajax.

Like convert image to binary and send to server if nothing normal works